# Are Jews allowed to use the expression "fingers crossed"?

Tags: halacha, words, avodah-zarah, christianity, hands-fingers

Not to worship idols is one of the 10 commandments; according to a quick Google search "finger crossed" originates from either the Christian cross or other superstitious beliefs.

Does this mean that using the term "fingers crossed" is forbidden for Jews?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36334/whats-the-jewish-equivalent-of-crossing-your-fingers

Comment: Somewhat similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5882

Comment: https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/93525